# how to write jquery toggle function in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing issue with toggle function in angularjs,I tried with ng-class but it is not working.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) 
 {
   $scope.showList=false;
    });
```

Here is my [Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/zT4lygVYorfNtIPejFs0?p=preview&preview) and my requirement must be like this [Plunker](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/ktQNuw84ITbxiG4PM1r3?p=preview&preview) with angularjs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-show to achieve:

```
<ul ng-show="showList">
                    <li>Get a quote</li>
                    <li>Send quote</li>
                </ul>
```

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/tGJmpYgM205gHnGC

Comment: Sorry it is not working,iam unable to see the toggle '+' and '-' signs

Comment: only change the 1st section "sign in data", click title you should see the toggle. Haven't change "+" and "-", because i think you can do it by yourself. Do you really need my help for the "+" and "-"

Comment: You are asking a question regarding using AngularJS to do the toggle function, responsive should be another CSS question.